# Avoid wrapping monads in a typed-tagless-final-style DSL

Tags: haskell, monads, dsl

Here's a small toy DSL in *typed tagless final* style (see [Typed Tagless Final Interpreters](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf) by O. Kiselyov).

```
class Monad m => RPCToy m where
    mkdir :: FilePath -> m ()
    ls    :: FilePath -> m [FilePath]
```

The different instatiations of this little DSL would be, for example, the implementation of `mkdir` and `ls` on different platforms, either local and remote. Type `m` is a monad in all implementations, it could be `IO`, or one provided by some networking library, or some other homebrew monad.

Here's an implementation in `IO`:

```
import System.Directory (listDirectory)
import Control.Monad (void)

instance RPCToy IO where
    mkdir = void . putStrLn . ("better not create "++)
    ls    = listDirectory
```

and a little application

```
import Control.Monad (unless)

demo :: RPCToy m => m ()
demo = do
    files <- ls "."
    unless ("test" `elem` files) $
        mkdir "test"
```

that can be run in the `IO` monad

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    demo
```

So far so good.

Now suppose that different implementations rely on the same monad `m`, e.g. from the same networking library. For the typed tagless final style to work distinct monads are needed, here, that are nonetheless essentially the same. The ambiguity can be removed by wrapping things:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Local a = Local {runLocal :: IO a} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

and then implement `RPCToy Local`,

```
instance RPCToy Local where
    mkdir = Local . putStrLn . ("BETTER NOT CREATE "++)
    ls    = Local . listDirectory
```

that can be run nicely

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    runLocal demo
```

**What bugs me is this:** The implementers have to put a lot of `Local`s in their code, or, rather repetitively, wrap the library functions like so

```
localListDirectory = Local . listDirectory
...
```

One idea is to create an 'indexed monad' `im i a`, `im i` being the monad, that carries around an index type `i` for the sole purpose of letting the compiler distinguish the different implementations. The `RebindableSyntax` extension makes this possible without having to give up the `do` syntax. But each monad needs to be 'lifted' into this indexed monad. The improvement is this: Each monad `m` and the functions therein need to be lifted only once. Otherwise it's still quite convoluted.

I'm wondering whether there's a nicer way to get rid of the monad wrapping.

Comment: Have you looked at extensible effects, like [freer-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-simple-1.2.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Freer.html)? In that approach this particular problem wouldn't happen (although you might of course have other problems with it).

Comment: @Cubic I've looked at free monads, but not at `freer-simple` in particular. What I like about the tagless final style is that it's easily extendable, so implementers can easily tack on their own actions, e.g. platform specific calls in this example. Maybe freer-simple can do that, too. Let me have a look.

Comment: Another relevant library is `polysemy`. Take a look at that too: https://haskell-explained.gitlab.io/blog/posts/2019/07/28/polysemy-is-cool-part-1/index.html

Comment: `freer-simple` doesn't implement free monads; it implements *freer* monads :) (The difference being that a free monad constructors a monad from a functor, while a freer monad constructs a monad from *anything* with type `Type -> Type`.)

Comment: @arrowd My superficial understanding of `polysemy` is that it addresses the problem of how to compose monads. That's not really the problem I'm having here, is it?

Comment: Could you clarify where the repetitiveness occurs? Are you complaining about instances that look the same because they just rewrap `IO`'s instance for the most part, or are you exposing additional toplevel functions specialized to your custom monads?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Both, actually. First: If I have `m` implementations that use `n` functions in `IO` then I have to wrap `n m` function calls, whereas I'd like that to be just `n`.  Second: When implementers create utility functions (in `IO`, say) then they can't easily share them with other implementers. In other words, there's no code reuse for new toplevel functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach: Introduce a monad transformer that just wraps another monad with the twist of adding a phantom type `i`,

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (MonadTrans, lift)

newtype IndexedWrapT i m a = IndexedWrapT {runIndexedWrapT :: m a} 
            deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance MonadTrans (IndexedWrapT i) where
    lift = IndexedWrapT
```

The phantom type `i` has the sole purpose of letting different implementations have distinct type.

Then wrap (`lift`) the relevant functions once, e.g.:

```
putStrLn' :: MonadTrans t => String -> t IO ()
putStrLn' = lift . putStrLn
```

On the implementation side

```
data MyImpl'

type MyImpl = IndexedWrapT MyImpl' IO

runMyImpl :: MyImpl a -> IO a
runMyImpl = runIndexedWrapT

instance RPCToy MyImpl where
    mkdir = putStrLn' . ("BETTER NOT CREATE "++)
    ....
```

Having formulated the wrapping operation as a monad transformer it becomes clear that other approaches to composing effects may be used, here, as pointed out in the comments, e.g. [freer-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-simple-1.2.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Freer.html) or [polysemy](https://haskell-explained.gitlab.io/blog/posts/2019/07/28/polysemy-is-cool-part-1/index.html).